# Find String in Multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, contains

## Scenario

I've got an `ArrayList<[String, String, String, String]>` to store data.
Now I'm trying to check if the `ArrayList` contains `String`.

```
for(String i : checkArtefakts){
            System.out.println(i);
            if(headerAndBodyTestSuites.toString().contains(i)){
                System.out.println(i + "  " + headerAndBodyTestSuites.indexOf(headerAndBodyTestSuites.contains(i)));
            }
        }
```

I've implemented a `toString()` Method but it also didn't solve my problem.

## Question

How can I check each `Element of ArrayList ([String,String,String,String])`

if it contains my `search String`.

And why wouldn't it even find it in my `toString()` method?

```
public String toString() {
    return "[XQ: " + xqueryFileName + "] [Path: " + testDir + "] [INP: " + firstInputFile
        + "] [INP: " + secondInputFile + "] [EXP: " + expectedFile + "]";

}
```

## Example

`ArrayList<HeaderAndBodyTestcase>` where `HeaderAndBodyTestcase` =

```
public HeaderAndBodyTestcase(final String xqueryFileName, final String testDir,
        final String firstInputFile, final String secondInputFile, final String expectedFile)
```

Comment: You can create some better data structure then `ArrayList ([String,String,String,String])`

Comment: What type is `[String, String, String, String]` ?

Comment: What are you recommending?@Abubakkar

@TimBiegeleisen it's of time `HeaderAndBodyTestcase` which takes 4 Strings.

Comment: You want to check if one of the four string of you object (for each of the list) is equals to `search string` ?

Comment: @azro Exactly      .

Comment: but there is 5 strings, so which 4 ?

Comment: There is a list with 5 Strings and 4 Strings each element @azro

Comment: You are so unclear ..

Comment: @azro here here

Comment: Seeing as `ArrayList<[String, String, String, String]>` doesn't compile, I'd sort of like to know what it is you meant. Did you mean `ArrayList<String[]>`? Or based on previous comments, did you mean `ArrayList<HeaderAndBodyTestcase>`?

Comment: The last one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a method in the class which will look if the search String is one of the attribute :

```
public boolean objectContainString(String search) {
     return Arrays.asList(xqueryFileName, testDir, firstInputFile, secondInputFile, expectedFile)
                  .contains(search);
}
```

And use like this :  `boolean bool = list.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.objectContainString(search));`

Comment: @0x45 you can think about vote up answers you like/thank ;)

Comment: I did but my Reputation is too low >:-(

Comment: @0x45 I vote up your question so you get more than 15rep so you can vote up whenever you want ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you were using `List<String[]>` you can use [**Arrays.asList()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), to check if the `String[]` contains your string with `.contains()` method.

But in your case it's a `List` of `HeaderAndBodyTestcase`, so you need to implement a `contains` method in your `HeaderAndBodyTestcase` class to check if any of the class members is equal to the searched `String`.

This is how should be your code:

```
public boolean contains(String search){
    return this.xqueryFileName.equals(search) || this.testDir.equals(serach) || this.firstInputFile.equals(search) || this.secondInputFile.equals(search) || this.expectedFile.equals(search);
}
```

Comment: `contains` instead of `equals ` solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @0x45 great, glad it helps, yes using `.contains` is better if the members `String` s contains other characters thatn the searched ` String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple as this:

```
    String searchedString = "SomeString";
    boolean found = false;
    for(String string : arrayList) {
          if (searchedString.equals(string)){
              found = true;
          }
    }
```

Or you could use the java stream API. (Requires Java 8)

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("SOME_STRING_1");
    list.add("SOME_STRING_2");
    list.add("SOME_STRING_3");
    String searchString = "SOME_STRING...";
    if(list.stream().anyMatch((string)->string.equals(searchString))) {
        // The string was in the list
    } else {
        // The string was not in the list
    }
```

Where arrayList contains your strings. Im not sure what you meant by ArrayList<[String, String, String, String]>, but this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @0x45 Aha, you want to check if a search string is a substring of any of the strings in the arraylist? Ex. ["hello", "goodbye", "hello goodbye"], then you supply it with for example: "ello", and you would get string at index 0, and 2? Yes?

Comment: I just want to check if it contains the string, I don't care about the index. But generally yes

Comment: instead of `list.stream().filter((string)->string.equals(searchString)).findFirst().isPresent()`use `list.stream().anyMatch(...)`